# Can't access django development server on a remote vps

Tags: django, ubuntu, vps

I've just got a VPS with Ubuntu 18.04 on it.
Now I want to move my Django app I've been developing on a local PC to the VPS. I moved it and it starts okay - it says the server is running on 0.0.0.0:8000.

So the server is running fine, but I can't connect to it from a web browser on my local PC. Note: I'm trying to access it with ip of the server (ip:8000)
I have port 8000 enabled with netstat and I have added the IP to ALLOWED_HOSTS.

Update: I managed to access it using ngrok. By running the command ngrok http 8000 I got the url with which I was able to access the server.
Now I'd like to know how can I access it with IP.

Comment: What error do you get? Connect timeout? Can you access it locally (ssh to server and run something like `curl http://127.0.0.1:8000`).

Comment: Yes, connection timeout (doesn't pop up in  the django console like there was a new get request on connect). Locally it works fine (when called from the ssh).

Comment: Check IP tables and make sure that the server is accessible from outside.

Comment: Yes, it is accessible. As I said, when I setup a ngrok url pointing to localhost:8000 it works like expected, but using the ip it doesn't